# rank of $A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $a_{ij} := i +j \quad \forall 1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $a_{ij} := i +j \quad \forall 1 \leq i, j \leq n$.
Find the rank of matrix $A$ and prove its value of every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(
\begin{pmatrix}2  
\end{pmatrix})&=1\\
\operatorname{rank}(
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix})&=2\\
\operatorname{rank}(
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 5\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{pmatrix})&=2\\
\operatorname{rank}(
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{pmatrix})&=2 \\
\operatorname{rank}(
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\end{pmatrix})&=2 \\
\end{align}$

I have no idea how to start that task. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the rows $(2,3,\ldots,n+1)$ and $(3,4,\ldots,n+2)$ lie in the row span and so their difference $(1,1,\ldots,1)$.

Now, each row $(i,i+1,\ldots,n+i-1)$, $2\leq i\leq n+1$, is a linear combination of $(2,3,\ldots,n+1)$ and $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, namely

$$(i,i+1,\ldots,n+i-1) = 1 \cdot (2,3,\ldots,n+1) + (i-2)\cdot (1,1,\ldots,1).$$

This shows that the row space (rank) of the matrix is $2$.

For instance $(n=5)$:

$(3,4,5,6,7) = (2,3,4,5,6) + (1,1,1,1,1)$

and

$(4,5,6,7,8) = (2,3,4,5,6)+ 2\cdot (1,1,1,1,1)$.